# Как преобразовать переменную из int в строку в методе?

Tags: java

Как изменить тип данных переменной, которая имеет тип данных `int` в параметрах метода в `String` при `return` в основной метод в Java? Это возможно?

[Ссылка на код](https://pastebin.com/t5TvEyVq), может кто подскажет как решить проблему с return и типами данных?

Comment: То есть вы хотите сделать метод, преобразующий `int` в `String`?

Comment: скинул ссылку на код, чтобы понятнее было, а то я скорее всего не описал проблему должным образом

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изменить тип данных переменной вы не можете.
Вы можете либо преобразовывать типы через upcasting или downcasting, выделяя для этого новые переменные, либо если типы несовместимы, как строки и целые числа - тогда использовать методы конвертации данных.

Отвечая на ваш вопрос:

```
String convert(int a) {
    return String.valueOf(a);
}
```

Comment: return "" + i; //

Comment: @ОлексійМоренець можно и так, но так есть вариант, что ТС узнает о методах конвертации